# How to receive data from html form POST at other html page?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, post

I have a html page called `index.html`. Inside it I use js to send JSON to other page (`loja.html`) and right after that I load this page. I would like to read the contents of JSON on `loja.html` and use it to populate some html tags. Here's my code:

piece of `index.html`'s

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajax.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        alert(ajax.status);
        }
    }
ajax.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/DBRest/loja.html",true);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
ajax.send(dataToJSON(nome,idade));
console.log(dataToJSON(nome,idade));
window.location = 'http://localhost:8080/DBRest/loja.html';
```

piece of `loja.html`'s js:

```
window.onload = function() {
        alert('alert');
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (ajax.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                alert(ajax.status);
                alert(JSON.parse(ajax.responseText));
            }
        }
    }
```

When I load `loja.html` from `index.html` none of alerts are displayed. when typed on browser, only first alert is displayed. How can I correctly send data to `loja.html` from `index.html` and after it immediately load `loja.html`?

Comment: Javascript lives/executes within the current browser window/location; if loja.html isn't currently loaded, it won't do anything as the javascript on that page hasn't been run. You'll need a server-side component to accept the GET (not POST) request that you're making and store the data. loja.html can then load that via Javascript.

Comment: Didn't know this. I'll try your suggestion asap.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Please submit this comment as an answer for me to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript lives/executes within the current browser window/location; if loja.html isn't currently loaded, it won't do anything as the javascript on that page hasn't been run. You'll need a server-side component to accept the GET (not POST) request that you're making and store the data. loja.html can then load that via Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options to move data between pages:

1. Store Data in Local Storage
2. Store Data in a cookie
3. Add data to the URL via query parameters
4. Query the database on the new page to retrieve the data.

Without using a SPA, there isn't a direct way to move data from one html page to another html page.